# Before Trigger or After Trigger when DML needs to be performed on two diff objects

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, after-trigger

I am confused on which Trigger event to use, Before or After.
Say, for eg. I have a trigger on Account. In trigger handler logic I need to update a field on Account (same object, hence we would prefer before trigger to avoid extra DML) but I also needs to update a field on its related Contacts. Since this involves an update on different object, so ideally which event should we go for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do both. It's not an either-or proposition. Do update records that are in the current trigger context with a before trigger and do update records that are related to the current trigger records with an after trigger. The "one trigger per object" best practice doesn't mean that you can't have logic both before and after saving the record.

Comment: Currently I have used a before update trigger on Account.
Scenario is whenever the postal code of account is updated then,
1. Check all its contacts & if atleast one contact has different zip then set Out Of Zip checkbox on Account to true.
2. Also, there is one custom object that contains two fields 'ZIP' and 'New Owner'. Now, I get the new owner from this custom object and update that owner on the Account, its contacts & its opportunities

I have written this logic inside one method in helper class.
How do you suggest I do this considering the best practices and a clean code?

Comment: @Aditya Strictly speaking, it would be best to update the account owner in the before trigger event, and the contacts and opportunities in an after trigger. Doing this consistently will make your triggers more predictable.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable inputs @sfdcfox. Will try this out :)